# Multi-column ordering using HTML5 data- attribute

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to use the multi-column ordering in jQuery DataTables as HTML5 `data-` attributes. Is this even possible?

I've already tried this:

```html
<th>Firstname</th>
<th data-orderData="[ 3, 2 ]">Lastname</th>
```

but it didn't work, while this works fine:

```html
<th data-orderable="false" data-searchable="false">Edit</th>
```

and I've tried to declare it as table `data-` attribute like this:

```html
<table id="myTable" data-columnDefs="[ {'targets': [ 5 ], 'orderData': [ 5, 3, 2 ]} ]">
```

but this also didn't work, while this works fine:

```html
<table id="myTable" data-order="[[ 5, 'asc' ], [ 3, 'asc' ], [ 2, 'asc' ]]">
```

I couldn't find anything in the official documentation about multi-column ordering with HTML5 `data-` attributes. Is this even possible to realize with HTML5 `data-` attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### CAUSE

See notes on [HTML5 data-* attributes](http://datatables.net/manual/options#HTML-5-data-attributes) page:

> There are two important points to consider when using `data-*` attributes as initialization options:
>
> - jQuery will automatically convert from dashed strings to the camel case notation used by DataTables (e.g. use `data-page-length` for `pageLength`).
> - If using a string inside the attribute it **must** be in double quotes (and therefore the attribute as a whole in single quotes). This is another requirement of jQuery's due to the processing of JSON `data-` data.

#### SOLUTION

You need to use `data-column-defs` instead of `data-columnDefs` and make sure you're using **double quotes** in option names.

```html
<table data-column-defs='[ {"targets": [ 3 ], "visible": false} ]' id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

or

```html
<table data-column-defs="[ {&quot;targets&quot;: [ 3 ], &quot;visible&quot;: false} ]" id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2cdgmgqq/2/) for code and demonstration.